# Make git clone its own repository

Tags: git, github

This question may have already been asked, but after searching I cannot find what I am looking for.

I created a project and pushed it to github a while ago, and then decided to use that as a type of boiler plate for a new project. So I cloned it to my desktop and then completely re-designed it. After the project was finished I decided to create its own repo on github and try to push it up. This however ended up in my redesigned project reverting back to its original state. I was able to correct this by hitting CTRL Z on all my files (LOL).
I need to find a way to completely separate the projects. When I try to push the original file to git hub, I get the following error:

"Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
(e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again."

To clarify, I do not want to merge or pull the two projects together, or end up deleting one of them. If it is possible I would like to find a way to make the cloned project its own, and then correct the error stated above for the original project.

Answer (score 7):

Say your boilerplate is at `git@github.com:foo/boilerplate.git` and you want that to be the basis of your new project `git@github.com:foo/project.git`.

On the github web site, create an empty repository called `project`.

Clone your boilerplate repo into a new directory called `project`.

```
git clone git@github.com:foo/boilerplate.git project
```

Git remembers that remote address so it can push/pull from there by default. But you don't want that: instead, from now on, you want `git push` to push to the `project.git` repo on github, not the `boilerplate.git` repo. `git remote set-url` is how you tell git that `project.git` is your new origin (*i.e.*, the default remote for pushing and pulling).

```
cd project
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:foo/project.git
```

Now, `git push` will push to the `project.git` repo.

Optionally, add the boilerplate as a separate remote (but not `origin`, so you won't use it by accident):

```
git remote add boilerplate git@github.com:foo/boilerplate.git
```

Now, when you update your boilerplate, you can merge those changes into your project as well. (This can work well if the boilerplate files tend not to change very much in your `project` repo.)

```
git pull boilerplate master
```

To roll back the `boilerplate.git` repo to the point where you *wanted* it to diverge, you just need `push -f`. Two ways:

1. If you still have a local copy of the boilerplate repo from before you accidentally pushed stuff to github, just go back there and run `git push -f`. This will remove the "work that you do not have locally" from the boilerplate repo on github -- but you've already got that stuff in a separate repo now, right? (You should think at least twice before doing `git push -f`. Git is trying to help you avoid deleting stuff by accident. Don't delete stuff by accident on purpose!)
2. Clone boilerplate. Use `git log` to find the commit where you wish you had left it, say `abc1234`. Reset the github repo's "master" branch back to that commit by running `git push -f origin abc1234:master`.

To see where origin points to (and what other remotes you have), run `git remote -v`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!